# how to add full image view screen in iPad

Tags: ipad, uiimageview, uisplitviewcontroller

I am currently develop one app in which i have added split view controller through programmatically. which is done successfully.
in Which i show images in the view. when i tap the images it must be open in the full screen. currently it open in split view controller's detailviewcontroller. For open images in full screen i used this [MWPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser).
how to open those images in full screen not in split view controller's child view?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**Finally i have found a solution of this issue. first of all store the image array into your delegate array and pass the method in delegate where I remove the tabbar and add my image view controller. when i want to get out from image view, I just remove the current view and add the tabbar controller.